# hammer.js - detect / fire event on some sort of "panhold"

Tags: jquery, hammer.js

I am currently monitoring the `pan` event to detect a change in positioning from the starting point using:

```
var x = e.gesture.deltaX;
var y = e.gesture.deltaY;
```

This is working great while moving the cursor / touch around the given area, but my problem is that I also need the event to be fired as long as the user is holding the position of the pan.

The pan event is being fired repeatedly while moving - up to a few dozen times a second if panning rapidly. **This is perfect.** I stumbled upon the `press` event, but this event only fires if you are pressing, not if you are panning and then hold (like a `panhold` or `pantopress`).

Any ideas? I don't mind a (clean) solution involving timers or other creative ideas, if there is not an event that I can hook into.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to multiple Hammer events on the same listener.

So in your case `'pan press'` should work.

If that does not work you can try listening for:

`'panleft panright pandown panup panstart panend pancancel'`

That is currently working for me.

Comment: This in fact does **not** work for me. Before posting this question, my bind was `pan press` but I outlined in my question that the `press` bind only happens if you start a press, not if you start a pan that turns into a hold.

Comment: And as suspected, binding to the additional pan types is redundant, unnecessary, and most importantly does not solve my issue. I am not concerned with which direction the user is panning, just the change in position with an absolute x/y coordinate. Therefore, simply binding `pan` is sufficient.